# undefined reference to function error in c

Tags: c, undefined

```
#include <stdio.h>


int singleFib(int x,int a,int b);
int multiFib(int x);


void main(){
int n,i;
printf("How much?\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%5d. number:   %d   -  %d \n",i+1,multiFib(i),singleFib(i,1,1));


}

getch();
return 0;

}

int multiFib(int x){

if (x<2){
    return 1;
}
else{
    return multiFib(x-2)+multiFib(x-1);
}


int singleFib(int x,int a,int b){

if (x<2){
    return 1;
}
else{

    return singleFib( x-1, b,(a+b));
}

}
}
```

The error is in

```
singleFib(i,1,1) in `printf`
```

Whyis that problem?how can i solve that problem? i am using codeblocks

Codeblocks\Fiberonacci\main.c|14|undefined reference to `singleFib'|
The error is that.how can i solve?

Comment: You need to start indenting your code properly. Also, it's called Fibonacci, not Fiberonacci.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you not make a smaller example that fails in the same way? The question will be easier to answer, more useful to others, and you might just find the answer yourself this way.

Comment: Nested function is a GCC extension which some gcc-compatible compilers like icc do support. It's not portable.

Comment: This code is a good (or merely bad) example where proper indentation would have made the error immediately obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You're missing a close bracket `}` at the end of your `multiFib` function.
2. You have an extra close bracket `}` at the end of your `singleFib` function.
3. The function `main` should have return type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The `{` and `}` in `multiFib` and `singleFib` are mixed up, `singleFib` is declared inside `multiFib`:

```
int multiFib(int x){

    if (x<2){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return multiFib(x-2)+multiFib(x-1);
    }


    /*************************************/
    int singleFib(int x,int a,int b) {

        if (x<2){
            return 1;
        }
        else{

            return singleFib( x-1, b,(a+b));
        }
    }

    /*************************************/
}
```

it works in gcc, since it's an nonstandard [nested functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions) extension, but the function will not be accessible outside `multiFib`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a mismatch in the braces of the function definition

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket for `multiFib`, but have one that you don't need after `singleFib`.